# e.output is null on WF Completed event

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I am working with WF 4 and I want that when an activity failed, finshed the WF and send the callback to client with in/out argument.

but, on Completed event, the e.output is empty.

Why does it happen???

Answer (score 0):

If your workflow failed there is no output. So either use the exception to pass data to the caller or handle the exception in the workflow and have it terminate normally.

Comment: My callbackurl is dynamic and I get it as in/out argument. If the output is null, how can I return the client replay??